# Dew point and raining

Tags: water-resources

I recently learned about dew point and rain. From my understanding, dew point is the temperature at which the air can hold the amount of moisture present. And when the temperature decrease, the air can hold less moisture, so some of it must condenses, which comes down as rain. So with this fact, does the rain usually happens when the temperature decreases? Then how can we describe the rain which starts around noon (when it’s the hottest of the day)? Are there any other factors that causes rain?

Comment: Up where the clouds are may not be the same temperature as where you measure ambient...

Answer (score 2):

The important point here is that rain tends to form at some significant height above ground level. When you get water droplets condensing in situ it is usually referred to as *mist* or *fog* or *dew* when it condenses on surfaces.

Rain often happens when warm, moist air is forced upwards due to large sale movements of bodies of air in particular at the boundaries ([fronts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_front)) of warm and cold air with differnt humidity.

[image]